# NL500 - Gutshot straight draw improves equity on turn

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, online, hand-history

Players are all solid regulars in this game. The game is typically aggressive, but not wild.

---

- SB $250
- HERO $593 J♥ T♣
- UTG $883.63
- Cut-Off $279.25
- Dealer $352.98

Small blind posts $2.5
Big blind posts $5

*Preflop*

- UTG folds
- Cut-Off raises to $15
- Dealer folds
- Small Blind folds
- Hero calls $10

*Flop* (Q♦ 3♠ 8♦)

- Hero checks
- Cut-Off bets $25
- Hero calls $25

*Turn* (Q♦ 3♠ 8♦  K♠)

- Hero checks
- Cut-Off bets $60
- **Hero ?**

Answer (score 1):

I do think you can even consider folding just because of his sizing on the flop, but as played I would mix in some raising and folding on the turn.

You clearly can't be calling here, and since you have quite some equity and some good bluffing runouts like any diamond, raising like half of the time and folding the rest seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You win with A and 9 that is like 1/6. Not worth 60 call with 150 pot and only 180 stack of cut off.